# Ready function not working properly on loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code I'm using works but the click function triggers (the send) no matter where I click on the page and not just when I click the chat-send button. The chat-send button is on the loaded page.

```
$("#div-contents").load("___contents.php");

$("#chat-send").ready(function(){
    $(this).click(function() {  
      ///Do something
    });
});
```

This does not work for me as well:

```
$("#chat-send").ready(function(){
    $("#chat-send").click(function() {  
      ///Do something
    });
});
```

Comment: The first line is loading a ridiculously placed statement involving an element that probably not even existing yet.`$("#div-contents").load("___contents.php");` that happens before anything else can even begin...if `#div-contents` not on the page in the beginning but should be dynamically added later...then your logic is really fubared.

Comment: Have a look at this codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/async-bash-n6mji

Comment: I found a solution. Thanks for the replies.I used a simple setTimeout function.

Comment: paste the answer here and mark it as accepted, Thank you